# EAP-SIM and connman / How to connect?

Tags: linux, networking

I'm looking for how to connect to freeWifi (EAP-SIM auth required via SIM usb reader) with connman.
I know how to connect with wpa_supplicant through a config like this:

```
network={
ssid="FreeWifi_secure"
key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
eap=SIM
pcsc=""
pin="1234"
}
```

How to accomplish the same with connman config?
Thank you smile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just out of interest, connman doesn't support EAP-SIM.